# Connecting To Web Services through Xamarin

Tags: c#, web-services, xamarin, xamarin.android

I am new to Xamarin and am trying to connect to my client web services whose address is http://smartasset-utw.malaysiaairports.com.my:5010/service1.asmx?op=GetUserLogin. This is used to authenticate logins. The code that I have used is below.

```html
var httpClient = new HttpClient();
httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("text/xml"));
httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("SOAPAction", "http://smartasset-utw.malaysiaairports.com.my:5010/service1.asmx?WSDL");
string wUser = "XXXXX";
string wPassword = "xxxxxxxx";
string soapstr = string.Format(@"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8""?>
  <soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"" xmlns:xsd=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"" xmlns:soap=""http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"">
    <soap:Body>
   <GetUserLogin xmlns=""http://tempuri.org/"">
     <userName>{0}</userName>
     <password>{1}</password>
   </GetUserLogin>
    </soap:Body>
  </soap:Envelope>", wUser, wPassword);
var response = httpClient.PostAsync("http://smartasset-utw.malaysiaairports.com.my:5010/service1.asmx?WSDL", new StringContent(soapstr, Encoding.UTF8, "text/xml")).Result;
var content = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
```

Unfortunately, the response that I get is:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"><soap:Body><soap:Fault><faultcode>soap:Client</faultcode><faultstring>Server did not recognize the value of HTTP Header SOAPAction: http://smartasset-utw.malaysiaairports.com.my:5010/service1.asmx.</faultstring><detail /></soap:Fault></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>
```

Any help would be appreciated,
Thanks

Comment: i believe if you calling soap services in Xamarin then you need to add Soap Reference on your native Platform [try this](http://www.nullskull.com/a/10476774/consuming-web-services-using-xamarin.aspx), here you will see how to add soap reference to the native project and then make the interface in the portable class and implement your interface in native platform and then you call call them using dependency services

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Consume soap web service with Xamarin.Forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28353948/consume-soap-web-service-with-xamarin-forms)